# Graphviz: Graph with a node common in multiple subgraphs?

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-visualization, pygraphviz

The objective is to able to create graphs in which a node can be overlapping between two or more subgraphs. Something like in the (erroneous) image below (A->B and A->C are in different subgraphs):

[image: hypothetical graph with a common node]

Something similar has been asked in [Graphviz: Node in two subgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289530/graphviz-node-in-two-subgraph) and also in [Same node in two subgraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259081/same-node-in-two-subgraphs), but there had been no solution. This is something essential in graphs, and there should be an easy way of achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping subgraphs is not supported by GraphViz